# What interval does the median fall into when the values of the numbers before and after the median aren't specified and n is even?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, order-statistics

What interval does the median fall into when the values of the numbers before and after the median aren't specified, but are the last and first data points in the intervals sorrounding the median, assuming n is even?

e.g assume intervals (0, 5] (#1) and (5, 10] (#2), in a sample of n=10, where the median is the average of the values of data point 5 and data point 6, where data point 5 is the last data point in the first interval and data point 6 is the first data point in the second interval.

Which interval would the median lie? Can it be known, or do values for data point 5 and 6 have to be specified? Because:

If we assume data point 5 has a value of 5 and data point 6 has a value of 10, then the median is 7.5, making the median fall into interval 2. But if we assume data point 5 has a value of 0.1 and data point 6 has a value of 5, then the median is 2.55, making the median fall into interval 1.

I hope my explanation was clear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The last couple paragraphs in this post answer your question.  What else are you hoping for?

Comment: Someone to show me a flaw in my logic? I'm trying to answer an assignment question which has given a similar scenario and proposes that the median has to fall into one of the two intervals.